# Apple Music plays the beginning of my songs then restarts the song and plays it in full

Tags: itunes, music.app

I have a lot of music imported into iTunes (Apple Music) from CD and vinyl collection, all imported by album. When I want to listen to an album, it inevitably plays the 5 seconds of a song, then loops back and start over. The second time, it plays the whole song through with out a problem, When I get to the next song, it happens again - a 5 second preview, then the song starts again from the beginning and plays through. I'm on a 2015 iMac with the latest version of Big Sur. Any clues? Thanks in advance.